# Retrofit 2 Query, get back response?

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

How could i access with the correct syntax: **api/kiosk/search/staff?companyID={companyID}&locationID={locationID}&name={name}**

Right now i do this:

```
@GET("api/kiosk/search/staff?companyID={companyID}&locationID={locationID}&name={name}")
Call<Staff[]> staffItems(@Path("companyID") String companyID,@Query("locationId") String locationId, @Query("name") String name, @Header("Authorization")String auth);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
@GET("api/kiosk/search/staff")
Call<Staff[]> staffItems(@Query("companyID") String companyID,@Query("locationId") String locationId, @Query("name") String 
name, @Header("Authorization")String auth);
```